# How to use jQuery-One-Page-Nav and jQuery.SerialScroll togheter for enable "prev" and "next" buttons or arrows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, scrollto, serialscroll

I'm trying to have a one page solution with **jQuery-One-Page-Nav** for highlighting menu links when i reach some "sections" in the page (and click to scroll to respective sections).

Inside this sections i have some posts like the code

```
<body>
<nav>
    <ul class="menuslides">
        <li class="item-1">
            <a href="#section-1" >One</a>
        </li>
        <li class="item-2">
            <a href="#section-2" >Two</a>
        </li>
        ...
    </ul>
</nav>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="wrap"> 
        <section id="section-1">
            <div class="post" id="item-slide-1">img</div>
            <div class="post" id="item-slide-2">img</div>
        </section>
        <section id="section-2">
            <div class="post" id="item-slide-3">img</div>
            <div class="post" id="item-slide-4">img</div>
            <div class="post" id="item-slide-5">img</div>
        </section>
        ...
        <section id="section-10">
             <div class="post" id="item-slide-31">img</div>
             ...
        </section>
     </div>
     <div id="buttons">
         <div id="button" class="goto-prev">Prev</div>
         <div id="button" class="goto-next">Next</div>
     </div>
</div>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('.menuslides').onePageNav();             
    });

    jQuery(function( $ ){
        $('#wrapper').serialScroll({            
        target:'#wrap',
    items:'.post', 
    prev:'div.goto-prev',
    next:'div.goto-next',
    axis:'y',       
    duration:700,
        onBefore:function( e, elem, $pane, $items, pos ){           
                 e.preventDefault();
         if( this.blur )
                 this.blur();
             },
    onAfter:function( elem ){           
             }
    });
    });

</script>


</body>
```

I'm happy with the **jQuery-One-Page-Nav**, it works very well and i can navigate through  "**sections**" with the nav menu.

But i need to add two button or two arrows that **they work like a prev-next link** scrolling the page through my posts **class="post"**

I'm using 
https://github.com/davist11/jQuery-One-Page-Nav
and 
https://github.com/flesler/jquery.serialScroll
with **no weird changes to the code** (only renamed ids and classes) but I can not get them **coexist together**: it works only one of them!

Is there any solution to make them co-exist, or is there a snippet of code that will enable me to have these two functions at the same time?